# Android Fragment Tabs throwing error

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create 2 tabs and 2 different activities for 2 tabs. But throwing error during start activity.  Here is my code:

```
public class CashSales extends FragmentActivity {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.cash_sales_tab);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                CustomerAddActivity.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                ItemAddActivity.class, null);
    }
}
```

Here is my activity that will appear in one tab.

```
   public class CustomerAddActivity extends FragmentActivity {
        private EditText mName; 
        private EditText mEmail1;
        private Integer mPkid;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_add);

            mName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customer_add_name);
            mEmail1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customer_add_email1);
            Button confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.customer_add_button);
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''         
        }
    }
```

CatLog:

```
02-26 05:52:39.732: E/AndroidRuntime(25579): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 05:52:39.732: E/AndroidRuntime(25579): java.lang.ClassCastException: asia.wavelet.android.customer.CustomerAddActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
02-26 05:52:39.732: E/AndroidRuntime(25579):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:394)
02-26 05:52:39.732: E/AndroidRuntime(25579):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:339)
02-26 05:52:39.732: E/AndroidRuntime(25579):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:276)
```

Comment: have you tried `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are giving the `addTab` method an activity instead of a fragment here:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                CustomerAddActivity.class, null);
 mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                ItemAddActivity.class, null);
```

That's why the system is trying to cast the activity to a fragment and throwing a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

you should extends Fragment,not Fragment Activity.

like this.

```
public class CustomerAddActivity extends Fragment
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customer_add, container, false);
    }
```

Comment: Actually I am creating a POS app where first tab will be select customer. Second one select Item, 3rd to set payment. In the 4th tab there will be a preview and save option. By clicking save option it will save in database. So should I create only one FragementActivity which will hold all the tabs? Do I need to save data of each tab in session until get final save button? Only extending fragment will solve these?